# iOS 8 -- Apply blur to navigation bar AND status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8

I am attempting to add a blur effect to a navigation bar and a status bar. 
My problem is that the blur goes great onto the navigation bar, but the status bar does not get blurred.

**My question is: how can I extend the bounds to encompass the status bar?**

I'm using the following method to create the blur effect:

```
- (void) addBlurEffect {

CGRect bounds = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;
UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight]];
visualEffectView.frame = bounds;
visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:visualEffectView];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar sendSubviewToBack:visualEffectView];
```

}

In my plist, I have View controller-based status bar appearance `YES`

In viewDidLoad I call a method:

```
- (void)configureView {

    // style controls

    self.addAirportButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // style background image

    UIImageView *sidebarBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sidebarBackground"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = sidebarBackground;

    // style navigation bar

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;

    // this makes navigation bar transparent

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

    // style toolbar

    self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = YES;
    self.dismissAdsButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Nothing else important gets done in viewDidLoad.
When I build this, here is what the view looks like -- it's a tableViewController embedded in a NavigationController, and I'm using the excellent SWRevealViewController as well.

See how the status bar is not blurred:

[image: The blur is only in the navigation bar part - the status bar is not blurred]

Any help would be really appreciated!

UPDATE:

See answer below. Here is a screenshot of the implemented solution:

[image: screenshot with solution applied]

Comment: Have you tried calling all this from viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad when the view is about to appear for the first time?

Comment: I tried it, no change, unfortunatley.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been trying to accomplish similar effect, after tweaking with the UINavigationBar's API and could not achieve desired result, I found a workaround:

1. create a UIView the same size as your NavigationBar + StatusBar. That is, it would have a frame of (0, 0, w, 64), where w is the width of your screen. (I did this through Storyboard and used autolayout to set the width constraint to be equal to that of its superview)
2. set UIView's `backgroundColor` to clear color.
3. make the navigationBar completely transparent with the following code:
   `navBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
   navBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
   navBar.translucent = true`
4. now apply the blur effect to that View, this creates the illusion that the blur effect was from both the Navigation Bar and the Status Bar.

See [this picture](http://tinypic.com/r/2mwz953/8) for achieved effect (sorry I can't post image yet due to reputation restriction).

Hope this helps.

UPDATE 2015-05-28:

This is how I achieved the aforementioned method in StoryBoard:

1. Create the Navigation Bar Background View in the topmost hierarchy as a direct child of the main view. Note that everything else I have wrapped them into a single Content View. Content View is colored red and the Navigation Bar Background View is colored semi-transparent white.

[image]

[image]

2. add following 4 constraints on the Navigation Bar Background View like such: 0 for left, right, and top constraint, and 64 for height constraint.

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I'm going to try this out.

Comment: How were you able to add the UIView in the storyboard structure? Can  you post a screenshot of your storyboard and structure view?

Comment: hi @ChrisHolloway, i have updated my answer with screenshots. Don't hesitate to let me know if you need further clarifications.

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented and added a screenshot of the result to the original post